# How to prevent hammering on socket server when full?

Tags: c++, sockets

I'm writing a socket server designed to only host a small number of client connections.

When a user attempts connection, my server could do one of two things, AFAICT:

1. accept() the incoming socket connection, inform the user that the server is full, then close() the connection;
2. Simply ignore the attempt to connect, if the connections list is full.

I don't really like the second option, but it seems to me that the first invites trouble, where players (since this is a game) may try to hammer the server. Whereas if I simply ignore the attempts, there cannot be any problem in this regard.

What approach should I take?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'd say inform the client.

Hammering won't take down a server if it isn't a (or several) program(s) that hammers like crazy, opening lots of connections in parallel and really trying.

Let the user click on a button to connect and if the server is full, wait a second (or more) and then let the player retry, that way the client (the player) will be happy (he's in control) and he can't hammer more than like once a second (and who is going to sit and hammer manually for hours anyway).

Answer (score 2):

You could hold a queue for incoming connections, and accept() only a few according to the connection pool you decide to set.

I.e, you can decide to accept 5 connections at a time, and save in a queue the rest of the incoming connections,
and act according to your current state - once you have a free connection, accept a connection from the queue.

Comment: No... this has minimal practical use. It's easier to eject the client after telling them to try again later, or ignore them outright. In fact what you're advocating is the much the same as my option 2, since they will get no response whatsoever until a slot becomes available. "Do I ignore annoying people on the street or do I politely tell them to leave me alone?" The problem is that acknowledgement can bring more trouble than it's worth.

Comment: Using an incoming connections pool is a common approach for issues like this.

Comment: It might be easier for you to "eject the client after telling them to try again later", but for them it is a major hindrance. When connecting to a game, I'd rather know that I am in a queue and that the connection will be made eventually (I can even estimate when based on my position in the queue) rather than being told to try again later (how much later? One minute? Ten minutes? One hour? Do I have a guarantee that later I will be able to connect? Or will I have to try again and again with no result? I'll probably get annoyed quite rapidly and go play some other game).

Comment: agree with @Nick and I would add that having a queue is dangerous for scaling. Clients use to have a timeout for connecting to servers. When the waiting (in queue) client is processed by the server, the timeout may already be close to the limit, and will fire while the server is starting its processing. So the connection will fail eventually with a waste of resources on the server. It's better to quckly reject the clients if we are full (with a message if it doesn't waste too much resources) and only process "fresh" clients when we have capacity to do so. (seen in real cases)

Answer (score 0):

Third option: Use iptables to limit the number of incoming connections

Comment: This game server could be hosted on any user's machine. I'm not sure iptables is even remotely applicable here.